# How can I add a space after every two characters in .txt file?

Tags: python, txt

The input I have is a large strain of characters in a `.TXT` file (over 18,000 characters) and I need to add a space after every two characters. How can I write the code to provide the output in a `.TXT` file again?
Like so;

- Input:

```
 123456789
```

- Output:

```
 12 34 56 78 9
```

Answer (score 2):

The `enumerate()` function is going to be doing the heavy work for you here, all we need to do is iterate over the string of characters and use modulo to split ever two characters, a worked example is below!

```
string_of_chars = "123456789101213141516171819"
spaced_chars = ""

for i, c in enumerate(string_of_chars):
  if i % 2 == 1:
    spaced_chars += c + " "
  else:
    spaced_chars += c

print(spaced_chars)
```

Comment: Thank you! This does seem like the appropriate tactic, however I'm not sure on how I can provide the input from a .txt file and enable output?

Comment: Are you needing to save back to the file?

Comment: I require the spaced input so that I can encode it as per the format I need it in. If it's to the same file then that would be ideal? (I'm sorry, this is literally my first day learning python)

Answer (score 2):

This will produce `12 34 56 78 9`

```
t = '123456789'
' '.join(t[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(t), 2))
```

If  the file is very large, you won't want to read it all into memory, and instead read a block of characters, and write them to an output handle, and loop that.

To include read/write:

```
write_handle = open('./output.txt', 'w')

with open('./input.txt') as read_handle:
    for line in read_handle:
        write_handle.write(' '.join(line[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(line), 2)))

write_handle.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
txt = '123456789'
print(*[txt[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(txt), 2)])
```

output

```
'12 34 56 78 9'
```

Comment: My bad thanks a lot @Shijith I didn't realize that I'm missing quotes

Comment: Note that this relies on the `sep` argument of the `print` function but OP is not interested in printing, rather than writing to a file and `file.write(*[txt[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(txt), 2)])` will not work...